# How do I get Firebase's project name from Android?

Tags: android, firebase

I have an app with Firebase integrated. We switch back and forth between project "Development" and project "Production" in Firebase.

[image]

On Android, switching the project is done by replacing the `google-services.json` file. Is there any way I can get the Firebase's project name (i.e. **Temu Production** and **Temu Development**) from inside Android? Something like `FirebaseApp.getInstance().getProjectName()`?

I'm new to Firebase so I'm open to various approaches on project management and infrastructure.

Comment: I prefer use single project with multiple android app, so you will have `com.example` as production app and `com.example.debug` as debug app. Try opening **Setting gear icon > Project setting > Tab "General" > look for "Your apps"** below it you can see list of your app in your selected project and also can add one too

Comment: If you're moving files around to build different versions of your apps for different environments, you're probably doing too much work.  Instead you can use build flavors to easily build the different versions without moving any files.  Then you can use the build flavor to determine any differences in behavior.  My blog post about this is here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The project name is provided by the `FirebaseApp` class.

Android:

`FirebaseApp.getInstance().getOptions().getProjectId()` should do the trick.

iOS (Swift):

`FirebaseApp.app()?.options.projectID` works well.

Comment: It worked for me (Android)
@Okihita can you accept this answer if it helped you?